# Encryption - symmetric key

Tags: vb.net, encryption, key, aes, rijndael

I’m using Rijndael (as AES algorithm) for encrypting. I encrypt the values (objects properties) and serialize the object to xml an dsend the xml to the receiver via a web service. I want to pass along the encrypted symmetric key that I used to encrypt the data. But what key should I pass along?
My decryption algorithm looks like this (vb.net):

```
Public Function Encrypt(ByVal stringToEncrypt As String) As String

    Dim textConverter As New ASCIIEncoding()
    Dim myRijndael As New RijndaelManaged()
    Dim encrypted() As Byte
    Dim stringToEncryptAsByte() As Byte
    Dim encryptedAsString As String
    Dim key() As Byte
    Dim IV() As Byte

        ' Set symetric key size og chiper mode
        myRijndael.Mode = CipherMode.CBC
        myRijndael.KeySize = 128

        ' Create a new key and initialization vector.
        myRijndael.GenerateKey()
        myRijndael.GenerateIV()

        ' Get the key and IV.
        key = myRijndael.Key
        IV = myRijndael.IV

        ' Get an encryptor.
        Dim encryptor As ICryptoTransform = myRijndael.CreateEncryptor(key, IV)

        ' Encrypt the data.
        Dim msEncrypt As New MemoryStream()
        Dim csEncrypt As New CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write)

        ' Convert the data to a byte array.
        stringToEncryptAsByte = textConverter.GetBytes(stringToEncrypt)

        ' Write all data to the crypto stream and flush it.
        csEncrypt.Write(stringToEncryptAsByte, 0, stringToEncryptAsByte.Length)
        csEncrypt.FlushFinalBlock()

        ' Get encrypted array of bytes.
        encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray()
        encryptedAsString = Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted)

        Return encryptedAsString
End Function
```

If I want to decrypt the encrypted string I have to use both key and IV, but I think I have to pass along only a key value. Do I have to do this another way or what should I pass along?
My specification says that the values have to be encrypted using AES and a 128 bits key.

Answer (score 1):

If you pass the encryption key along with the encrypted data, this is equivalent to not encrypting the data at all (other than one can't read it with plain eyes, but then a simple Base64 encoding or similar would do the same.

To use a symmetric encryption algorithm, sender and receiver *must share a secret* (the symmetric key, or something from which the key can be derived). If this is not possible, you might want to use a hybrid symmetric/asymmetric encryption scheme: Here the sender encrypts the secret key using a public key algorithm, and sends it together with the symmetrically encrypted data. (In this case, the sender must know the public key corresponding to the receiver's private key.)

That said, with chaining modes of operation for block ciphers (like CBC), the sender usually passes the initialization vector along with the data.

Answer (score 1):

The IV is simple, just send it as-is.  It is common practice to prepend it to the cyphertext so the receiver just strips it off when needed.  There is no need to keep the IV secret.

The key is not so simple because it **must** be kept secret.  There are two general solutions:

1. Use Diffie-Hellman to agree a new secret key with your recipient each time you need to send them an encrypted file.
2. Use their RSA public key to encrypt the AES key and send it to them that way.

You may also want to investigate the use of HMAC to ensure that the file has not been tampered with during transmission.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I want to encrypt my symmetric  key with PKI (X509 certificate). What I can’t figure out is what the receiver wants, just the key or both the key and IV. In my specification (from the reciever part) of how to encrypt the data it says that I have to pass along my encrypted symmetric key but I can’t find anything about the IV. How do I know that the receiver also uses IV, or expect me to pass along an IV?

Comment: @Liss: Tell your receiver that the first 16 bytes of the main file you are sending are the IV.  Then it is up to them what to do with it.  IVs don't need to be secure.  Only the key needs to be secure.

Comment: @Liss: CBC (and in fact all modes other than ECB) always uses an IV, the question would only be how to transfer it. The usual way is to simply prepend it to the encrypted data.